# Differences in Django deplyoy with uWSGI vs Nginx, error: The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2

I tried too much yesterday deploy my first Django project. I search a lot of questions there, too similars, but nothing worked.

I've following this: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

And when I run my django project with only uWSGI, it works great:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

But when I run my django project with nginx, I got the error **"The included urlconf doesn't have any patterns in it"**.

I tried this (after tested the helloworld wsgi <-> ngix working nice):

```
uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --module mysite.wsgi --chmod-socket=664
```

There's my urlconf file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.index', name='index'),
url(r'^estudantes/', include('students.urls', namespace='students')),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^contato/$', 'mysite.views.contato'),
url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
url(r'^galeria/', include('galeria.urls', namespace='galeria')),
url(r'^hashtags/', include('hashtags.urls', namespace='hashtags')),
url(r'^contas/', include('contas.urls', namespace='contas')),
url(r'^sair/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout',
    {'template_name': 'index.html'}, 'sair'),
url(r'^entrar/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'students/login.html'}, 'entrar'),
url(r'^lista_usuarios/$', 'mysite.views.lista_usuarios',
    {}, 'lista_usuarios'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Anybody help?

I'm using AWS EC2 Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do all of the included urls.py files (ones you include with `include()`) point to files which contain patterns?  You could comment out individual lines to see which one(s) are causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, every url are filled and working directly on uWSGI. But not when I try nginx. I'm giving up Aws Ec2 and trying to deploy on heroku :(

Comment: Is the nginx config you're using rewriting the URL?  Maybe Django is getting confused by the URL it's getting from nginx.

Comment: I don't know, how can I check this?

Comment: I'm really not certain if this is related, and I'm fairly new to nginx myself, but check this: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,222445,222448#msg-222448

Comment: Apparently Django is seeing an empty urls.py somewhere, so the only thing I can figure is that nginx is looking somewhere different than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was restart from zero!

I followed the heroku deploy tuto and didn't work too... So I removed all the apps, third apps, etc... And tried deployed app by app since django welcome blank page. Now it's working, the problem was Django Debug Tool Bar...